# Is there a standard machine readable format for flowcharts?

Tags: algorithm, flowchart, financial, tax

Before UML came to existence, Germans specified flowchart symbol language as a national standard in the year 1983.

It is called [DIN 66001](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programmablaufplan).

Even today, German authorities use this standard to communicate for example their [income tax algorithms](https://www.bundesfinanzministerium.de/Content/DE/Downloads/Steuern/Steuerarten/Lohnsteuer/Programmablaufplan/2018-11-12-PAP-2019-anlage-1.pdf?__blob=publicationFile&v=1). They are also available as [XML](https://www.bmf-steuerrechner.de/interface/pseudocodes.xhtml) but as it seems without schema.

**Question:** is there actually a machine readable (de facto) *standard* format for such flow charts? Be it XML schema or XSLT?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say "before UML", as you certainly know in UML you have to use an activity, and if you export your model in XMI you will have the definition of your activity inside (I don't speak about the diagrams/graphical representation).

What is the problem, the fact you can have more than the activity into the exported model ? the fact the activity can reference/use extra elements depending on how the activity is defined ?

Comment: What is XMI and which export do you mean?

Comment: XMI is the UML standard export format, it is an export in XML respecting UML rules